# .htaccess Relative Path to ErrorDocument

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

So I have an apache server with subdomains with subdirectories. I turn my directories into subdomains. So instead of `example.site.com/mycoolsite` it's `mycoolsite.example.com`. Or in other words I turn `/var/www/mycoolsite` into `/var/mycoolsite`. I do this with the .htaccess file with the below code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycoolsite.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mycoolsite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mycoolsite/$1 [L]
```

Great. Now it turns the directory into the subdomain. The problem now is that .htaccess can't reference the ErrorDocument I setup for my original subdomain. I can go to `example.site.com/mycoolsite/aNonExistantDirectory/` and get the proper 404 I have setup, but when I try `mycoolsite.site.com/aNonExistantDirectory/` I get the basic server 404 error page, not the one I have setup. Both are on the same server. To get around the problem, I can make a copy of the error documents and put them inside the `/mycoolsite/` directory but I'm hoping I can simply reference the original error documents.

The problem is, I don't know how to reference the error documents in `/var/www/error/` to `/var/www/mycoolsite/` I've tried:

```
ErrorDocument 404 ../error/index.php?p=404
ErrorDocument 404 /www/error/index.php?p=404
ErrorDocument 404 www/error/index.php?p=404
ErrorDocument 404 error/index.php?p=404
ErrorDocument 404 /error/index.php?p=404
```

None of those work. When try it without the first `/` or preceding `..` it will display the error document line on the page. I'm stumped. I hope I included enough information, but if not, let me know.

Comment: I don't think apache lets you reference files outside of the current document_root. It's a security thing. What you can do is create a dummy php file that just contains a `include(../error/index.php)`.

Comment: This works! If you want to put that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think apache lets you reference files outside of the current document_root. It's a security thing. What you can do is create a dummy php file that just contains a `include(../error/index.php)`